# How to stop an infinite event loop in asyncio with no name?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have the following code:

```
import asyncio
import time

class displayName:
    def __init__(self, name, delay, exit = False):
        self.name = name
        self.delay = delay
        self.exit = exit
    async def start(self):
        #displays name of object at regular time intervals
        self.exit = False
        print('starting display program...')
        while True:
            if self.exit == True:
                print('ending display program')
                break
            print(self.name)
            await asyncio.sleep(self.delay)
    async def stop(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        self.exit = True
    async def update_name(self, name):
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        self.name = name
    async def update_delay(self, delay):
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        self.delay = delay
```

Normally, I would execute:

```
display = displayName('Tom',5)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(display.start())
```

and if I wanted to change the name being displayed I would execute:

```
loop.create_task(display.update_name('Jerry'))
```

and to stop the loop I would execute:

```
loop.create_task(display.stop())
```

which changes display.exit to True and ends the loop.

However, if I attempt to execute this code using:

```
asyncio.run(display.start())
```

then I cannot get the loop to close!

I've tried:

```
loop1 = asyncio.get_running_loop()
loop1.close()
```

and this did nothing.
I can do a keyboard interrupt, but any time I try to run another task with asyncio.run(), I get an error message saying that asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop!

How do I close this active loop so that I can use asyncio.run() again??!!!

I am working in a Jupyter Notebook, if this is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I scoured the internet and I found the following hack that seems to work:

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
```

When I run this code it seems to cause Python to "forget" all the earlier asyncio.run() commands, and now I can use asyncio.run() to run other blocks of code as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Your class has no errors. The error is the way you're using `run()` method.

When you execute `asyncio.run(display.start())` the program will wait to that coroutine to finish. So, in this case you're runing `display.start()` that is an infinite loop. That's the reason why can't do anything else while that coroutine runs.

You have to call in `asyncio.run()` a coroutine that manages all the instructions. See the code below:

```
import asyncio

class displayName:
    def __init__(self, name, delay, exit = False):
        self.name = name
        self.delay = delay
        self.exit = exit
    async def start(self):
        #displays name of object at regular time intervals
        self.exit = False
        print('starting display program...')
        while True:
            if self.exit == True:
                print('ending display program')
                break
            print(f'name: {self.name}     delay:{self.delay}')
            await asyncio.sleep(self.delay)
    async def stop(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        self.exit = True
    async def update_name(self, name):
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        self.name = name
    async def update_delay(self, delay):
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        self.delay = delay

async def main():
    x = displayName('Tom', 1) #Create an instance of displayName
    task = asyncio.create_task(x.start()) #Run x.start()
    await asyncio.sleep(3) #waits 3 secs
    await x.update_name('Chris') #Change name
    await asyncio.sleep(3) #waits 3 secs
    await x.update_delay(0.5) #Change delay time
    await asyncio.sleep(3) #waits 3 secs
    await x.stop() #Stop task
    await task #Wait for task to end

asyncio.run(main())
print("This sentence will NOT be executed concurrently...")
print("This will be executed once asyncio.run() is done")
```

##### Output:

```
name: Tom     delay:1
name: Tom     delay:1
name: Tom     delay:1
name: Tom     delay:1
name: Chris     delay:1
name: Chris     delay:1
name: Chris     delay:1
name: Chris     delay:0.5
name: Chris     delay:0.5
name: Chris     delay:0.5
name: Chris     delay:0.5
ending display program
This sentence will NOT be executed concurrently...
This will be executed once asyncio.run() is done
```

The solution you gave works, but it's not at all the recommended way to do it

Comment: I'm trying to write a code (in Jupyter) where I can change the name displayed to a new name any time I want just by entering a new command, so I don't want to define the timing of the change ahead of time.
For some reason I'm able to do this if I use the code that I showed above:

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(display.start())
##wait some amount of time##
loop.create_task(display.update_name('Jerry')
##wait some more time##
loop.create_task(display.stop())

but I'm unable to do this with asyncio.run().
Why do these two methods give different results?